# How to manipulate an array so that it returns as json structure in PHP?

Tags: php, json, array-push

I am trying to loop through a json object and push selected values into an array.

```
$json = '
{
    "canonicalUrl": "/v1/products(offers.type=deal_of_the_day)?format=json&apiKey=946n9vuhdkgeyz2qx2dpxd54",
    "currentPage": 1,
    "from": 1,
    "partial": false,
    "products": [
        {
            "active": true,
            "activeUpdateDate": "2014-11-03T19:43:46",
            "lowPriceGuarantee": true,
            "name": "LG - 1.1 Cu. Ft. Mid-Size Microwave - Black",
            "new": false,
            "onSale": true,
            "productId": 1219180376135,
            "regularPrice": 124.99,
            "salePrice": 99.99,
            "sku": 5998225,
            "source": "bestbuy",
            "startDate": "2014-07-06",
            "type": "HardGood"
        },
        {
            "active": true,
            "activeUpdateDate": "2014-11-03T18:03:02",
            "lowPriceGuarantee": false,
            "name": "Rocketfish In-Wall HDMI Cable",
            "new": false,
            "onSale": true,
            "productId": 1218343205770,
            "regularPrice": 29.99,
            "salePrice": 24.99,
            "sku": 2634897,
            "source": "bestbuy",
            "startDate": "2011-08-14",
            "type": "HardGood"
        }
    ],
    "queryTime": "0.004",
    "to": 2,
    "total": 2,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "totalTime": "0.020"
}

';

$json_output = json_decode($json);
$pBB = array("title" => array(), "type" => array());
foreach($json_output->products as $obj){
    array_push($pBB['title']," {$obj->name}");
    array_push($pBB['type']," {$obj->type}" );

}
echo  json_encode($pBB);
```

the output of above code is

```
{
  "title": [
    " LG - 1.1 Cu. Ft. Mid-Size Microwave - Black",
    " Rocketfish In-Wall HDMI Cable"
  ],
  "type": [
    " HardGood",
    " HardGood"
  ]
}
```

i want to to return it as below

```
[
  {
     "title": "LG - 1.1 Cu. Ft. Mid-Size Microwave - Black",
     "type": "HardGood"
  },
  {
     "title": " Rocketfish In-Wall HDMI Cable",
     "type":  " HardGood"
  }
]
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `[]` is an array. but in JS, arrays cannot have non-numeric keys. **ANY** non-numeric keys requires using an object (`{}`).

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do a "grouping of values" in each field for a PHP array. It makes more sense to access `$pBB[0]['title']` rather than `$pBB['title'][0]`... so you should fix that...

Comment: `$pBB = array();` & `$pBB[] = array('title' => $obj->name,'type' => $obj->type);`, which does seem a lot more logical for both JSON and PHP itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [my comment on your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26787691/how-to-manipulate-an-array-so-that-it-returns-as-json-structure-in-php/26787801#comment42151854_26787691), you have used an unconventional method of organizing your products into values, where you should instead be organizing each product into separate array for each product containing its title and type. Use this instead:

```
$json_output = json_decode($json);
$pBB = array();
foreach($json_output->products as $obj){
    $pBB[] = array(
        'title' => " {$obj->name}", // Not sure why you're using " {$obj->name}" but I preserved it
        'type' => " {$obj->type}", // You could just use $obj->type directly
    );
}
echo  json_encode(array_values($pBB));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$json_output = json_decode($json);
$pBB = array();
foreach($json_output->products as $obj){
    array_push($pBB, array(
        'title' => " {$obj->name}",
        'type' => " {$obj->type}"
    ));
}
echo  json_encode(array_values($pBB));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this! you need to create object and push into array.

```
$json = ' { "from": 1, "to": 2, "total": 2, "currentPage": 1, "totalPages": 1, "queryTime": "0.004", "totalTime": "0.020", "partial": false, "canonicalUrl": "/v1/products(offers.type=deal_of_the_day)?format=json&apiKey=946n9vuhdkgeyz2qx2dpxd54","products": [ { "sku": 5998225, "productId": 1219180376135, "name": "LG - 1.1 Cu. Ft. Mid-Size Microwave - Black", "source": "bestbuy", "type": "HardGood", "startDate": "2014-07-06","new": false, "active": true, "lowPriceGuarantee": true, "activeUpdateDate": "2014-11-03T19:43:46", "regularPrice": 124.99, "salePrice": 99.99, "onSale": true},{ "sku": 2634897, "productId": 1218343205770, "name": "Rocketfish In-Wall HDMI Cable", "source": "bestbuy", "type": "HardGood", "startDate": "2011-08-14", "new": false, "active": true,"lowPriceGuarantee": false, "activeUpdateDate": "2014-11-03T18:03:02", "regularPrice": 29.99, "salePrice": 24.99, "onSale": true } ] }';

$json_output = json_decode($json);
foreach($json_output->products as $obj){
    $new_obj = new stdClass();
    $new_obj->title = $obj->name;
    $new_obj->type = $obj->type;    
    $pBB[]= $new_obj;
}
echo  json_encode($pBB);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is error with building JSON object. Actually the string you pass in json_decode function is okay, but problem occurs when you build an JSON object from array.

dont use

$pBB = array("title" => array(), "type" => array());

instead try

$pBB = array(array("title"=>$title,"type"=>$type));

When you encode $pBB into Json, i guess it will give you exact output.

Happy Coding.
Atul

Answer (score 0):

```
echo  json_encode($pBB);
```

You need to make sure it seems like it can be an array to JS (ie sequential numbering)

Replace the above line with

```
echo  json_encode(array_values($pBB));
```

To make it work as expected

array values returns sequential ints as the keys